# my filter is working but doesnt work when i use it with ionic

Tags: angularjs, filter, ionic-framework

I am trying to filter my application based on the category it belongs to
my json is in the form -

```
{
      "id": "8",
      "image":"img/final7.jpg",
      "title": "The Heavy-Nosed Plane",
      "category":"Acrobatic",
      "difficulty": "Hard",
      "cuts": "zero"
    }
```

I want to filter from the property of category and i have been able to create a filter that does what what i want that is illustrated in this [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/kOfm85?p=preview)
But when i add the logic to my ionic app it does not work as you can see in this [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/QxK7Tv?p=info)
Please Help me :(

Comment: I dont understand if i bring my categories into the view that is my Paper-planes tab then i am able to filter but they are not getting filtered if i am using them through a different view..

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/QxK7Tv?p=preview 
Check this link .. I have two buttons on the header which are filtered the div's i have right beneath them. But the same buttons with same logic when i am trying to use on the menu (sidebar) they are not working ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are used `PlaylistsCtrl` for menu page and playlists page. Even though it is same controller, they have different instances. So `$scope.filter` in one controller is not the same in other controller.

updated [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/KCEVXuszTlb6Dw1fmjUO)

Comment: Ok.. so what is the solution to this? 
Should i use a factory/

Comment: try to use a settings service or a value provider to keep all the settings.
Or you could use rootScope for this.

Comment: can you help me .. ? i am unable to figure out how to do that

Comment: Oh we can share scope by using rootScope! Thanks buddy